# Viewing .gdb ESRI data in QGIS 3.4.5

Tags: qgis, arcmap, file-geodatabase, domains, subtype

I am trying to use file geodatabase (`.gdb`) data in QGIS.

I have tried opening the dataset in ArcMap but I keep getting an error message so trying in QGIS.  I have got as far as opening and viewing the data however, the data in the attribute tables are just numbers.  These numbers relate to feature type names that would show up in ArcMap via the 'show domain and subtype descriptions' button.

Is there a way of doing this in QGIS?  The data is pretty much useless without this link.

Comment: This seems like an XY Problem. If ArcGIS can't read a file geodatabase, it's because the FGDB is has been corrupted. You should be focusing on the error provided by ArcMap to better understand whether the data is lost, or whether Tech Support can help you recover it.

Comment: The .gdb file opens fine in QGIS and i can view it and interrogate the attribute table etc. So it does not seem be to corrupt in anyway. It is just the reference file to change the numbers in the attribute table to words needs to be linked in am assuming.

Comment: Right, the domains are corrupted.